# Custom on-the-fly conversion into shapefiles

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, convert

I have a custom binary format, for which I run an external program to output a set of `.shp` files, which then can be dragged and dropped into QGIS.

What would be the best way of pushing this into some QGIS hook that would do all of this behind the scenes to support something like this:

1. Custom binary file is dragged into QGIS
2. QGIS calls the external program, which outputs the `.shp` files into some temporary folder.
3. QGIS shows the temporary folder

Browsing through the plugin docs of QGIS 3.4 I didn't find a clear guidance wrt. where I could intercept the drag'n'drop / file-loading process. Also given the excellent Python-extensibility of QGIS, I suspect that there is already some support for my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct solution to your problem, but there are some possible solutions.

The hard way:
Write an OGR (GDAL) provider, see: https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc76_ogrpythondrivers.html

The easier way:
Write your own plugin/processing algorithm which calls the external program and loads the converted shape files, see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html

Your question is too general to answer it in detail.